# Self assigned IP address

Tags: macos, wifi, network

I've done a clean install of OS X El Capitan recently, and everything worked fine.

But as I came home, I couldn't connect to Wi-Fi. It states that it has a self-assigned IP address and will not connect to the Internet.

I've been on many forums, and found no solution. Wi-Fi normally worked before the clean install and it still works on my side system, Kali Linux, which I'm writing from right now.

I've tried to get OS X forget the Wi-Fi and then input the password again, but nothing changed. I've tried to enter a valid IP that I know it's working (I got to it through an app which remembered my computer on the Wi-Fi back when it worked), but still no Internet for me.

The Wi-Fi has WEP encryption and I'm not able to access the router to change any settings, because the owner (which is not me) refuses to let me do some adjustments.

Answer (score 3):

A self assigned IP address suggests that your system did not receive an IP address from a DHCP or similar protocol.  As Otto Andy Heiskanen mentions, restarting the DHCP server (by rebooting the router) can solve this issue often.  However you mention your Linux environment does get an IP address, which could point at a different cause.  You also mention that you are not allowed to access the router's settings: are you able to physically access it to pull the power plug?

If you can't access it physically, I recommend you compare the settings in the Linux environment with the settings in OS X.  Is the Linux environment getting an assigned IP address, or is it a fixed IP address?  Perhaps your linux environment is using a MAC address that is different from your physical MAC address?  Maybe there is some newly configured MAC address filtering enabled on the router?

Comment: I've already tried restarting the router by pulling the plug out of it for two minutes, but after it got back up i still couldn't connect. If it was mine wifi, I would've just reseted it, if I had access to it and it would work. Isn't the WEP encryption the problem? My friends wifi, that it worked on, had WPA and IPs were 10.0.0 instead of 192.168.1. Isn't that the problem?

Comment: I have even reinstalled whole OS X,  but I couldn't even join the Wi-Fi in the bootable flash drive interface. That means the problem is in the OS X itself. When I got the Mac, it was second hand, so the person before me could have installed some drivers, or something like that? I've tried searching for mac wifi drivers, but nothing came up. Any ideas?

Comment: WEP should be fully supported by OS X, however it's not so commonly used anymore so maybe there is an unknown issue.  The IP ranges is certainly not related, 10.0.x.x and 192.168.x.x are standard compliant IP subnets for private networks.  As to the drivers: after reinstalling OS X you will have all the necessary drivers for Apple hardware.  Only if the previous owner changed the hardware would you need to install drivers, it does not seem very likely since you are able to see the Wifi networks when scanning: this implies the Wifi hardware and driver are functional.

Comment: In short: I think the most likely conclusion from the information you have provided is that El Capitan does not like the WEP network as offered by the WiFi hotspot.  I would expect it's in everyone's interest (including the owner of the Wifi hotspot) to replace the Wifi hotspot, since WEP is really not secure anymore.  Get a secondhand wifi hotspot with minimal 802.11n support.  This should not cost more than USD15 and will be more stable, faster and more secure.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, did you look at this part of my previous answer? "I recommend you compare the settings in the Linux environment with the settings in OS X. Is the Linux environment getting an assigned IP address, or is it a fixed IP address? Perhaps your linux environment is using a MAC address that is different from your physical MAC address? Maybe there is some newly configured MAC address filtering enabled on the router?"

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is with the router. I have had this type of case before and rebooting router usually helps. If not, then reseting router is the next option.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled this problem for a few days. It only happens on my home wifi. Finally, I reseted my router and it worked!